# In how many ways if no two people of the same sex are allowed to sit together?

Tags: combinatorics

### Question

> In how many ways if no two people of the same sex are allowed to sit together if there are $3$ boys and $3$ girls?

#### My Approach

I found out all possible seats of the girls after fixing boy's seat
$$-B-B-B-$$
After fixing boy's seat  I have $\binom{4}{3}$ ways to select possible seat for girls.

After seat has been allocated to both boys and girls
there are $3!$ ways for **girls** to change seat among themselves
and $3!$ ways for **boys** to change seat among themselves.

Total number of ways is $\binom{4}{3}\cdot 3!\cdot 3!=144$,
but the answer is given as $72$.

Where am I wrong? Please help me out! Thanks!

Comment: how many seats?

Comment: Is this what you mean: "In how many ways can three girls and three boys sit in a row, if no two people of the same sex can be seated next to one another?"

Comment: Hundred of answers in just a minute

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you are considering $6$ seats in a row. We can start with a boy or a girl and then sex is alternated i.e. $BGBGBG$ or $GBGBGB$ (2 ways). We have $3!$ ways to arrange the boys and $3!$ ways to arrange the girls. Hence the total number of ways is
$$2\cdot 3!\cdot 3!=72.$$

Comment: i know this approach .i want to know that what is wrong in my method!

Comment: @laura Well. I do not understand your $\binom{4}{3}$. Why $4$? The seats are $6$.

Comment: because i have $4$ avaliable seats

Comment: @laura Why $4$ available seats? I am sorry but I do not understand this initial step.

Comment: see the dash $-B-B-B-$ .coorect me if i am wrong

Comment: @laura There are seven symbols here $−B−B−B−$. What does $−B−B−B−$ mean?

Comment: i mean i have $-$ here which corresponds to seat that is avaliable to girl

Comment: @laura  The method of placing girls in the gaps between the boys is appropriate if no two girls may sit in adjacent seats.  However, if both ends are filled by girls, it leaves two boys in adjacent seats.   Thus, it will not work here, as boys and girls must alternate.

Comment: got it ! thanks a lot @N.F.Taussig

Comment: @laura if you place $G_1$ in one of the 4 seats say $-BG_1B-B-$ then in how many ways you can fill the seat of the other girls.  What about the case $G_1B-B-B-$? The two numbers are different!

Comment: @RobertZ had it been "no two girls must seat together" ,my approach  would have work ! isn't it?

Comment: in $\binom{6}{3}$ ,how you got the *6* , i am getting *5* as mentioned above!

Comment: @laura Without the restriction for both boys and girls we have $\binom{6}{3}3!3!=6!=720$ ways. If the restriction holds only for boys then your approach is correct  and the number of ways is 144.

Comment: thats correct ! this statement is the golden statement ! :)

Answer (score 3):

You can have Boy-Girl-Boy-Girl-Boy-Girl or Girl-Boy-Girl-Boy-Girl-Boy

You can arrange the boys in $3!$ ways and the girls in $3!$ ways.

The answer is thus $2\cdot 3!\cdot 3!=\boxed{72}$ ways.

Answer (score 1):

The groups of different three girls into different seats:
$$
3!
$$

And the group of three different boys into different seats:
$$
3!
$$

And the way they can sit is just:
$$
2
$$
because they are interlaced $BGBGBG$ or $GBGBGB$. No other ways are possible when two $GG$ or $BB$ are allowed.

The result is 72 as requested.
$$
3!3!2=72
$$

Answer (score 1):

You have six seats so the two possible combinations are:

> Boy Girl Boy Girl Boy Girl
>
> Girl Boy Girl Boy Girl Boy

For each arrangement, you have 3! ways to arrange the boys and 3! ways to arrange the girls. Therefore the result is:

```
Number of possible combinations * Number of ways to arrange the boys * Number of ways to arrange the girls
```

Value: $$2 *3!*3! = 72$$