# In how many ways can we split 6 boys and 6 girls to 6 tables such that in every table there's a boy and girl (only 2 seats per table)

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

In how many ways can we split 6 boys and 6 girls to 6 tables such that in every table there's a boy and girl (only 2 seats per table)?

I saw this post and I think it's kind of the same of my question

[In how many ways if no two people of the same sex are allowed to sit together?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2322135/in-how-many-ways-if-no-two-people-of-the-same-sex-are-allowed-to-sit-together?newreg=f6c6a56ffeb74e0cb057aa26ed881105)

And the answer is $2*(6!)^2$

But then I saw this one (e) -

[Discrete Mechatronics - sequences with repeats and no repeats](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2068253/discrete-mechatronics-sequences-with-repeats-and-no-repeats)

Which says the answer is $2^6*(6!)^2$

I would like to know which one is correct in my case and why? (like what are the differences)

Comment: Do you count $BG$ and $GB$ as $1$ possibility or $2$?

Comment: 2 possibilities.

Comment: Can you have $BG$ at one table, then $GB$ at another table? The first assumes you can have either all girls on the left and boys on the right or all boys on the left and girls on the right. The second assumes that each table can be different with the gender of the person on the left and right, so long as there is a boy and girl at each table.

Comment: Yes. I can have any order of them, as long as each table has 1 boy and 1 girl.

Comment: Then the second answer is correct.

Comment: Are the tables distinguishable?  That is, if after everybody is seated, the two children seated at one table get up and switch with two children seated at another table, is that the same seating arrangement or a different one?

Comment: Can you explain in a more detailed way? like every part of the calculation and why?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang this is the full question, I don't think it will answer your question:
How many ways are there to seat 6 girls and 6 boys in 6 different tables of size 2, so there is one boy and one girl on each bench?

Comment: There are many ambiguities here.  It is traditional to consider each person as being distinguishable.  Now, as for the tables themselves, it is unclear whether these tables are distinguishable or not. If we have an arrangement where Amy and Adam are at a table and Bob and Bernadette are at another table, this might be considered the same outcome as where Bob and Bernadette are at a table and Amy and Adam are at another table or they might have been considered different.  If, say, at one table they are serving fish and at another table they are serving chicken, if Amy has an allergy it matters

Comment: Then, it also matters whether we consider arrangement within a table to matter.  If we have an arrangement where Amy and Adam are at a table, and so on, is this necessarily a different arrangement than an arrangement where Adam and Amy are at a table...  Maybe one of the chairs at the table is 20 feet high and the other chair is very short.  If Amy is scared of heights, it matters to her whether she is in the 20 foot chair or not.

Comment: The end result is that for questions like this, it must be made explicitly clear what makes one arrangement "the same" as another and what makes it "different" than another.  Depending on whether you consider arrangement within a table and labelings of tables relevent or not, you will get different answers.  If tables distinguishable and order at table relevant, you get $2^6(6!)^2$.  If tables indistinguishable and order at table irrelevant, you get only $6!$.  If tables distinguishable and order at table irrelevant, you get $(6!)^2$, etc...

Comment: @JMoravitz I totally get what you're saying but I have no idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix a table. Choose a boy and a girl for the table. Choose an order for the boy and girl.

You have six boys and six girls to choose from. Then, you can order them in two ways. So, this is $6\times 6\times 2$ ways to arrange one boy and one girl at the first table.

For the second table, you have five boys left, five girls left, and two ways to arrange then, entirely independent from the arrangement of the first table (the only dependency is that you have one fewer boy and one fewer girl to choose from).

So, there are $5\times 5\times 2$ ways to arrange one boy and one girl at the second table (after a boy and girl were already arranged at the first table).

For the third table, you have $4\times 4\times 2$ ways to arrange them. For the fourth table, you have $3\times 3 \times 2$ ways to arrange them. For the fifth table, you have $2\times 2\times 2$ ways to arrange them. For the last table, you have $1\times 1\times 2$ ways to arrange them.

Because each table is arranged independently from the arrangements of the previous tables, you can apply the product principle. So, the total is:

$$(6\cdot 6\cdot 2)(5\cdot 5\cdot 2)(4\cdot 4\cdot 2)(3\cdot 3\cdot 2)(2\cdot 2\cdot 2)(1\cdot 1\cdot 2) = 2^6(6!)^2$$

Comment: Perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In the first reference, the boys and girls are sitting in a line with no two people of the same gender are allowed to sit together. So there can be two cases. First in which a boy sits first and the second when a girl sits first.
While in your case as you've mentioned in the comments there can be two possibilities for each table GB or BG. Thus you have a multiplier of 2 for each table along with every permutation of boys and girls.

In other words, $2*(6!)^2$ is equivalent to the case when each table should have the same layout i.e either all the table should be BG or GB, while $2^6*(6!)^2$ is the case where each table can BG or GB independent of the other.

Comment: OK.
So, can I think about it as dividing into pairs(6!6!) and then choosing a table?

Comment: Yes. That would be a good strategy here.

Comment: @Combinatoric It is not clear what you mean by dividing into pairs (6!6!) and then choosing a table... 6! is choosing which boy (or girl) sits at which table.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe can you find another way to explain it? I want to make sure I really get it.

Comment: @Combinatoric assuming tables are distinguishable, for table A, pick a boy ($6$ options) then pick a girl ($6$ options).  Next, for table B pick a boy from those remaining ($5$ options) and then pick a girl from those remaining ($5$ options).  Continue until all tables have the people picked, giving $6\cdot 6\cdot 5\cdot 5\cdots 1\cdot 1 = 6!\cdot 6!$ options for distributing the people.  If we then care about which chair was used for each person at the tables themselves, for table A pick if the boy sat in the high chair or the low chair and let the girl sit in the other, for $2$ options, etc.

Comment: @Combinatoric in the event that we can't tell the tables apart, then instead, take the shortest boy and let him sit at any of the tables, it doesn't matter where and we won't keep track.  Then, choose a girl to go with him ($6$ options).  Then, the second shortest boy can pick a girl from those remaining ($5$ options).  Continue in this fashion to get $6\cdot 5\cdots 1 = 6!$ arrangements, again multiplying by some extra factors of two if you care about arrangement within the table itself.

Comment: @JMoravitz OK, I think I got it! Thanks!!